# React Native Screen Is Black, but found no problems on debugging

Tags: react-native

So I have been having this problem, I'm creating an app using the ignite template, which when I try using npx expo start, everything works fine. However, when I try react-native run-android, the build is successful, however the frontend just doesn't show up. I tried debugging using the console.log and they do show up, and the loading modal for the sync also shows up, just the screen itself doesn't show up. This made me confused, because my loading component can be seen, but my other component just doesn't show up. It show up like below.
[[image: Current situation]]

```
 LOG  Running "main" with {"rootTag":31}
 LOG  1
 LOG  2
 LOG  3
 LOG  hello
 LOG  fetch1
 LOG  []
 LOG  Creating tables successful
 LOG  Deleted existing MsShuttle data. Rows affected: 0
 LOG  Deleted existing TrBoarderInfo data. Rows affected: 0
 LOG  Deleted existing MsCard data. Rows affected: 0
 LOG  Deleted existing tabel_photo data. Rows affected: 0
 LOG  Deleted existing MsDriver data. Rows affected: 0
 LOG  4
 LOG  5
 LOG  6
 LOG  7
 LOG  hello
 LOG  Deleted existing MsDestination data. Rows affected: 0
```

i can see all my log on my ShuttlePickScreen showing up, just not with the FE I expected.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Screen
        preset="auto"
        contentContainerStyle={$screenContentContainer}
        safeAreaEdges={["top", "bottom"]}
      >
        <Image source={require("../../assets/images/Logo.png")} style={styles.logo} />
        <Text style={styles.shuttleNameTx}>Shuttle Name</Text>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedShuttle}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedShuttle(itemValue)}
          style={styles.picker}
        >
          {shuttleNames.map((shuttleName) => (
            <Picker.Item key={shuttleName} label={shuttleName} value={shuttleName} />
          ))}
        </Picker>
        <Button
          testID="login-button"
          text="CHECK IN"
          style={$tapButton}
          preset="reversed"
          onPress={handleCheckIn}
        />
        <Loading
          isSyncing={isSyncing}
          syncStatus={syncStatus}
          showLoading={showLoading}
          setShowLoading={setShowLoading}
          loadingContent={loadingContent}
        ></Loading>
      </Screen>
    </View>
  )
})
```

from my code you can see that the loading component is a part of my screen, but why my other component doesn't show up? i've tried replacing all of them with just a view and text component and they also don't show up.

Please can anyone help, any suggestion are very well appreciated!